# Passing data from controller superclass to view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm writing an Asp.net MVC application (my first MVC app). I need to pass data to the _Layout view to customize the header and footer on my pages - which user is logged in, if they have any notifications, etc. The _Layout page always needs this information, but the child pages do not.

How should I pass this data to the view? Can I create a `LoggedInUser` property that the view can access, in the same way there is a `Model` and `ViewBag`?  `LoggedInUser` could be populated by the base controller class.

Or is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MembershipProvider and/or RoleProvider you can do as webdeveloper pointed out to get the identity of the current user `User.Identity.Name`, if showing it's name is what you want.

Also you could type your `_layout` to use a specific model, but I don't recommend it. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4154407/544283)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155413/544283) for further details.

Lastly you could populate a ViewBag property on your controllers to have the user information you need.

I wanted to point out that you could do a partial view to achieve this, and avoid `_layout` typing and populating the ViewBag on each request.

Comment: Thanks, I initially had settled on inheriting all from one ViewModel and typing the _Layout, but I'll looking into partial views instead.

Answer (score 1):

To detect authentication:

```
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Then you can use sections [ASP.NET MVC 3: Layouts and Sections with Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)  or/and `@Html.RenderAction` ([Html.RenderAction and Html.Action](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx))