# How can I execute common code for every request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any possibility to find function like `Page_Load`? I have MVC application and I need run some code every page is loaded, or reloaded, or I call some controller. One shared function for everything classes?

I try Application_Start, but this execute only for first time application run. I search some like `BeginRequest`, but this function have been call several times, I need only first, when I load page and I need end function, like constructor and destructor for whole project.

Here is sample code.

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }  
}
```

`document.ready` isn't my case. And call function every controller is last option. The code must be executed before any other function have been called. And before all end, i need run end function. For example, at first I need created mysql connector shared for all classes. And at end I need close mysql connection.

Comment: you can use Layout in mvc

Comment: Call the function in your Controller.  This will be hit every time the page is loaded/reloaded.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for an [`ActionFilter`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-custom-action-filters)? `Application_BeginRequest` also fires for static files.

Comment: BeginRequest is good idea, but i tryed it, and function has been called several times, no only once.

Comment: @user1173536 I know, I was clarifying *why* it's called several times.

Comment: if you want to fire a particular method every time then you can call the method in Index() action for that particular view

Comment: as stated by @Stijn ActionFilter seems a very interesting option, allowing to keep lightweight Controllers, not hindering your code with a technically-focused hierarchy.

Comment: I second jbl's comment.  ActionFilters can be mixed/matched/added/removed to one or more controllers without the rigid constraints of an inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make all your controllers inherit from a custom BaseController:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        // your code here
    }
}

public class HomeController : BaseController // instead of Controller
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's better solution. And do you know, how i set destructor in BaseController?

Comment: Assuming you don't really mean "destructor" but "do something after the request is handled", you should use OnActionExecuted in the same way as OnActionExecuting. If you absolutely must do something when any controller is processed by the garbage collector, just define a ~BaseController() function as normal. Note that you have absolutely no control over when this function is being called.

Comment: Is there official documentation on the Controller Lifecycle somewhere? What other methods are available to override?

Comment: @styfle, there is great documentation of the whole MVC pipeline here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application . Recommend downloading the PDF found on this page for a better view.

Comment: But what if you need Dependency Injection in your BaseController?
And need an await for calling an API? The info from API should be used in all controllers.

Answer (score 8):

An update to Jan's answer. The `onExecutingAction` abstract method is public now not protected.

```
public virtual void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context);
```

So, you can't use the `protected` access modifier when you override. Make it public instead.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much I've spent hours trying to figure this out.