# How to use more than 1 Model on a page by using asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to use 2 models. The first is on `Index.cshtml` page, and the second is on `_Layout.cshtml` page

In the controller which contains the action `public ActionResult Index(){...}`, I declare some values and return it to View(). Like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   HomePageViewModel model = new HomePageViewModel();
   // do something...
   return View(model);
}
```

And in `MyProjectName.Models`, I write some classes to check login account and put it on the page `_Layout.cshtml`. Like this:

On page `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@using MyProjectName.Models
@model MyProjectName.Models.LoginModel

@if (Model.LoginAccount != null)
{
   foreach(Account acc in Model.LoginAccount)
   {
      @Html.ActionLink(@acc.Email, "SomeAction", "SomeController", null, new { id = "loginEmail" })
      @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "SomeAction", "SomeController", null, new { id = "logout" })
   }
}
```

The code on page `_Layout.cshtml` doesn't work. It said that: I have returned a model (`HomePageViewModel model`), but some values which I want to render is referenced from `MyProjectName.Models.LoginModel`

Main requirement is: the first model is used to display the content on page `Index.cshtml`, and the second model is used to check user login (on page `_Layout.cshtml`).

Can you tell me how to do that? Thank you!

Comment: For you particular case `Action(controller:login, action:ChildActionShowLinks ...)` would probably encapsulate view better... See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154407/asp-net-mvc-razor-pass-model-to-layout for more suggestions / discussion.

Comment: Create a joined view model that contains both models, and then pass that to your controller?

Comment: @DarkBobG I don't think it can fix my problem. Because if you create a `parent model` which contains 2 `child models`, it should work. But what happens if I reference `_Layout.cshtml` from another action?

Comment: Like: `public ActionResult AnotherAction() { OtherModel model = new OtherModel(); return View(model); }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout use `Html.Action()` or `Html.RenderAction()` to call a `ChildActionOnly` method that returns a partial view for `LoginModel`

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Login()
{
  LoginModel model = // initialize the model you want to display in the Layout
  return PartialView(model);
}
```

and create a partial view that displays the links, then in the Layout

```
@ { Html.RenderAction("Login", "yourControllerName") }
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use partial views and the ViewBag.

in your controller you would do something similar to this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Accounts = new AccountsViewModel();
        ViewBag.HomePage = new HomePageViewModel();

        return View();
    }
}
```

From here you'd pass your model from the ViewBag to a partial view

```
@{
    AccountViewModel Accounts = (AccountViewModel)ViewBag.Accounts;
}

@Html.Partial("_accountPartial", Accounts)
```

Comment: You mean that: Using ViewBag for login? If you make a new redirect, ViewBag data will be lost. But I will think back for `ViewBag.HomePage`. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting models in your _Layout.cshtml. You should be putting them into your views or partial views instead as _Layout.cshtml is used by all of your pages.