# Passing model to _Layout.cshtml (webapp version)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor

I would like to be able to pass a model to my base layout *_layout.cshtml* exactly like in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890109/15582774). The problem is that this example is only valid for the MVC framework and I use razor pages without MVC.

I saw that we could override the **Page()** method in a class inheriting from **PageModel** but I have the impression that it is not possible to provide the model at view creation time.

```cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel {
    public override PageResult Page() {
        return base.Page();  // how to pass a custom model?
    }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas or another way to do it I'm a taker. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I didn't think of it before. It's a simple inheritance with **PageModel** and your bound attributes is available in your _layout and in your final page. No need to create the view or to use a generic as with the MVC framework.

Here it is the very [simple solution](https://forums.asp.net/post/6284327.aspx) :)

Thanks to those who spent time searching

Answer (score 0):

The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47890109/15582774) you mentioned above is a much simpler and neater solution. From an architectural point of view, it is scalable and maintainable. This is the correct way of doing this. It has also been described simply. I don't know what is your problem with that.

BTW if you are using .NET Core you can also consider using Dependency Injection in your layout:

```
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Comment: Indeed I find the example perfect in my situation the problem is that it is given for .net core MVC (webapp MVC) and I do not use MVC but directly razor pages (webapp).

Comment: No. It is for Razor. you can easily apply it to your project.

Comment: Yes for razor MVC with controllers but in webapp without MVC you don't have any controller like in the example. Microsoft has implemented 2 types of webapp. The function it overloads is not the same in my case. In their case they inherit from Controller and in my case from PageModel.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. You can apply it for your PageModel

Comment: So I would like an example because it is not the same implementation. I can't even call the View() function.
Do you use razor mvc or razor without mvc?

Comment: I use razor and if I need web api in same project I use mvc too

Comment: Well I can't return a view from the Page() method because it's not a controller. If you know how to do it from a PageModel I would like you to tell me how to do it. Thank you :)

Comment: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/action-results

Comment: Yes, I know, what I am trying to do is to adapt the example given above to these methods which are not the same at all. At no time does it return a view on the page you gave me as in the example:
```csharp
public ActionResult Page()
{
    return View(new LayoutModel<Customer>(new Customer() { Name = "Test" }, "Title");
}
```

Comment: You can't assign a model to a PageResult because the model is not assignable.
```csharp
public object Model { get; }
in class PageResult
```

Comment: You can define your model with [BindProperty] attribute in your page model and access it in your razor view by @model YourModel directive.