# ASP.NET MVC error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Whenever I show this view `Index.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<Web_Course.Models.Movie>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Movies</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Movie</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var movie in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@movie.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I get this error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Web_Course.Models.Movie]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Web_Course.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel'

[image: Screenshot]

I made sure to pass `IEnumerable<Movie>` to the `View()` and the model in the view file.

Here is the controller:

```
public class MovieController : Controller
{
    // GET: Movie
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var movies = GetMovies();
        return View(movies);
    }

    private IEnumerable<Movie> GetMovies()
    {
        return new List<Movie>
        {
            new Movie { Id = 1, Name = "John Wick" },
            new Movie { Id = 2, Name = "Oppenheimer" }
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the `Movie` class:

```
namespace Web_Course.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        

    }
}
```

And here is the view model that is shown in the error:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Web_Course.Models;

namespace Web_Course.ViewModels
{
    public class RandomMovieViewModel
    {
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I don't know how this file is related to the error.

What is the issue here?

Comment: Are you sure you are accessing `Index` route from `Movie`  Controller from the browser? because I don't see any issues with the code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @GaganDeep Yes I am sure Movie/Index

Comment: Can you right click inside the `Index` method of `MovieController` and select Go to View and see to which view it takes you to..

Comment: @GaganDeep goes to the view I added up there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to fix the data model declaration in the `Index.cshtml` view to:

```
@model IEnumerable<Web_Course.Models.Movie>
```

You didn't show declaration of the `namespace` where the `Movie` item is declared.

In case after this update you still have an issue fix your question to show name space where the `Movie` class is declared.

***UPDATE:***

The problem in your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@using Web_Course.Models
@model Web_Course.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

By this line `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";` in your `Index.cshtml` you instruct the MVC engine to use this layout `_Layout.cshtml` when rendering the `Index.cshtml`. The view data model in this template is declared as `Web_Course.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel` type. But the current model in the `Index.cshtml` is `IEnumerable<Web_Course.Models.Movie>`. This is the reason why you got this error.

You can comment the following line in the `_Layout.cshtml` and the `Index()` action method will render the view without a problem:

```
@*@model Web_Course.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel*@
```

---

You can found lot of examples on the *StackOverflow* how to pass a data model to layouts. For example, see: [ASP.NET MVC Razor pass model to layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4154407/6630084)

Comment: It didn't work even after the update it shows the same error, I edited the post and the movie class now has the namespace `Web_Course.Models`

Comment: @CoverBasha: Now your question contains all the related parts of code and I'm sure your are already defined the data model correctly:  `@model IEnumerable<Web_Course.Models.Movie>`. Your code is compiling and running for me without any errors. Try the following: exit from the Visual Studio, remove `bin` and `obj` folders under your project directory, open your solution in the Visual Studio and make `Rebuild` your project.

Comment: Still the same error, so you think something is wrong with the project?

Comment: @CoverBasha: If you can load your project, for example, to the github - we will be able to simulate this bug. Currently, sources that you post doesn't meet to the error description.

Comment: Here: https://github.com/CoverBasha/Web_Course